# Output not coming as expected while using sql in oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle12c

I have a table **temp_zzz** which has:

[image]

My expected output is:

```
dataset pay bitable condt
A       B   C,E     ZZ
P       Q   D,F     YY
```

I have learned listaggs in oracle,but its not giving me expected output.

I tried is:

```
SELECT LISTAGG(bitable, ', ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY condt) "Product_Listing"
FROM temp_zzz group by condt;
```

It gave me :

```
Product_Listing
D, F
C, E
```

Is it possbile to get the expected result I expected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible:

```
SELECT dataset,
       condt,
       MIN(pay) AS pay,
       LISTAGG(bitable, ', ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY condt) "Product_Listing"
FROM temp_zzz 
group by dataset,condt;
```